# Run PHP file in batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I am trying to load php file from a batch file but that says could not open `C:\PHP\php.exe` though i have `php.exe` in that folder

My Batch code

```
"C:\PHP\php.exe" -f C:\PHP\php.exe" -f C:\inetpub\WWWROOT\testett.php

pause
```

PHP code for demo

```
<?php

    $myfile = fopen("D:\Log\attendance_SMS.txt", "a") or die("");
        $txt = "Url Info    ";
        fwrite($myfile, $txt.PHP_EOL);
        fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: You have unmatched quotation marks and a duplicated command on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have php. exe referenced twice in your batch file, use this instead:

```
C:\PHP\php.exe -f C:\inetpub\WWWROOT\testett.php

pause
```